# ImageJ: Execute commands with run() in JAVA

Tags: java, api, plugins, image-processing, imagej

I executed this "Enhance Contrast..." command 
(*in ImageJ: Process > Enhance Contrast...*) 
with the following JAVA code:

```
IJ.run(imagePlus, "Enhance Contrast...", "");
```

But, I don't know how to execute some other commands e. g.: 
*Process > Binary > **Make Binary***.

Finally, I would like to launch the plugin: Anisotropic Diffusion 2D. After dropping it to ImageJ it will be shown in:
*Plugins > **Anisotropic Diffusion 2D***.

**How can I execute both commands in my JAVA-code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful tool for answering these questions is ImageJ's macro recorder.  Open up *Plugins > Macros > Record ...* and change the "Record" option to `Plugin`.  If you then try to run the menu option for "Make Binary", you will see the following in the macro recorder:

```
IJ.run(imp, "Make Binary", "");
```

You can do the same for "Anisotropic Diffusion 2D".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it. First contrast and after binary. And it shows the following commands: .... IJ.run(imp, "Enhance Contrast...", "saturated=0.4");
IJ.run(imp, "Make Binary", ""); .... "Enhance Contrast..." is working but "Make Binary" just throws the unrecognized command message... in my compiled sourcecode ImageJ I can work with both commands with no problems. Any idea what the probleme could be???

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED, I don't know how to connect the source code of ImageJ to my eclipse without this behavior. But including the ij.jar file it will work correctly as explained above.